# self.context is not a function in Angular2 when calling a component function

Tags: angular, components

I want to call a function when I instantiate an angular2 component, but I get the following error: 
    TypeError: self.context.dummyFunc is not a function

The following is a contrived example, but will show you my problem.
Assume we have the following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'myItem',
      template: `<div>This will work->{{dummyFunc()}}</div>`,
    })
    export class myItemComponent {
      constructor() { }

      dummyFunc() :string {
        return "bold";
      }
    }
```

And the following HTML:

`<ul myItem [ngClass]='dummyFunc()'></ul>`

The following exception will be generated:

> TypeError: self.context.dummyFunc is not a function

If i change the HTML to:

`<ul myItem></ul>`

The component runs and is able to call the dummyFunc function inside the 
 `<div>`

I am assuming the dummyFunc() is not called in the context of the component myItem, but the component that instantiated myItem.

My question. What would be the proper way to call a function on the just created component when instantiating a component?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact, when you use `dummyFunc` on the `ul` element, you are outside the `myItem` component. So you can't use it. You only have access to properties and methods of the component associated with the current template.

If you want to use a method of a component used in this template, you need to reference it first. You could try the following:

```
<ul #comp myItem [ngClass]="comp.dummyFunc()"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector and the attribute need to match

```
selector: 'myitem',
```

```
<ul myItem
```

Either change the selector to `'myItem'` or the attribute to `<ul myitem`

Comment: That was another typo in my question. I should have created the question using my source code, but as the component in question was rather large I opted to try and create an example without using source.. Unfortunately including all the typos. (edited the question)

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer  can we use **<ul myItem></ul> shouldn't be like <myItem></myItem>**

Comment: @Danny sorry, but I don't understand your question. The original question was changed since I posted the answer, therefore my answer doesn't really make sense in this context anymore.